# How to analyse the effectiveness of mitigation methods on biological data and variables

Tags: r, modeling

I work in wildlife biology. For a project I am attempting, I am looking for a way to **assess the effectiveness of various mitigation measures using to protect specific target species**. I have a database with over 30 years of information on my target species' and various biological variables (season, hour, behaviour, etc.), as well as a suite of mitigation techniques I wish to explore, but I cannot think of a way to combine these effectively.

My initial thoughts were to use a GAMM, regression, or PCA model. I also thought about performing a risk assessment but I'm not quite sure that will do what I want. Ideally, I would use a quantitative assessment method but I have never heard of a method or way to do this. I know qualitative methods primarily involve monitoring the area before and after implementation, but this won't be field-based.

I'd love some ideas as I'm relatively new to statistics and modelling and am not quite sure which direction would be the best.

Thank you!

Edit: To elaborate further: I'm looking to assess the base data and then try different iterations of improving/weakening specific mitigation techniques and forcasting how the data might change.